# Which filter should be applied to the EEG signal for the stress stimulus?

Tags: measurement, eeg, brain-waves, analysis

I am a student in electrical and electronics engineering. I just started working with EEG. I perform a stress test on subjects and record EEG activities with a 5-sensor headset. I use Matlab for analysis. I'm wondering if anyone can tell me the best method for data analysis. Do we expect the signal to be localized at a certain frequency range in the EEG data under stress stimulus? If so, what is the frequency range? **Which filter should be applied to the EEG signal for the stress stimulus?**

Comment: Hi, welcome at CogSci. It very much depends on what you exactly are studying (e.g. ERPs, spectral power, coherence) and what kind of stress ( mental workload, physical straining, scare reflex) . Could you share some initial research you have done yourself about the matter, and perhaps explain a bit more about what you're studying. Otherwise, the question is too broad to receive a satisfying answer.

Comment: Have you implemented triggers/markers for the stressors, or do you only have continuous data? Typically, a simple FFT will not suffice. What locations do your electrodes have?